# Not getting a full response while sending ajax request to retrieve a whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am working with J-Query Ajax. What  I am trying to do is, I am sending a request to get the whole html data of a page I have hosted on **bitbaysolutions.com**. The problem is, when I load [this](http://bitbaysolutions.com/) URL and type `document.getElementsByTagName("div");` I get a list of **37** div elements in the console. But when i send ajax request to this same URL and filter the div elements by `$(response).find('div');` then I get the list of div elements reduced to **25** and the div i require with the class name `._myresult` is missing. And when I simply send the request without filtering it, and out put the result as `console.log(response);` then I get the whole html data, and the div element I require to get is present there. And when I try to filter for that div as, `$(response).find('._myresult'));` then what i get is this :

```js
[prevObject: n.fn.init(35), context: undefined, selector: "._myresult"]
context:undefined
length:0
prevObject:(35) [text, title, text, link, text, meta, text, link, text, link, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, div#login, text, div#signup, text, comment, text, div.fb-reg, text, comment, text, div._myresult, text, div#thanks, text, div#thanks_login, text, script, text]
selector:"._myresult"
__proto__:Object(0)
```

From the above result you can see that the length for that filter is 0, and even you can see that the `div._myresult` is present in the html and I can get it without filtering it. But when I try to extract I do not get the required element.

**The J-Query Ajax I tried**

```js
$.ajax({
  method:"get",
  url: "http://www.bitbaysolutions.com",
  complete : function(){},
  success: function(response){
    var data = response;
    console.log(data);
    //console.log($(data).find('div'));
    //console.log($(data).find('._myresult'));  
  }
 });
```

> You can visit this [URL](http://bitbaysolutions.com/) and type `document.getElementsByClassName('_myresult')` or `document.getElementsBytagName('div')` to check for the class I need and the number of div elements present there.
>
> **Note**: I have displayed the https://www.bitbaysolutions.com page in my chrome extension page in an iframe. Like : `<iframe src="http://www.bitbaysolutions.com" id="myiframe" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;border:none;overflow-y:scroll; "></iframe>` and I making the cross origin Ajax requests which is possible in extensions only.

Concluding everything, I need to get the div element with class name **._myresult** through Ajax request. That is all I need.

Comment: Evidently the page dynamically adds the elements by running a script. XHR/AJAX doesn't run scripts. You'll have to embed the URL in an iframe and inject a content script to get the elements and send the text back via messaging or try to find the data you need in another place of the downloaded html (sometimes it may be in a json object which you can parse out).

Comment: No, that elements are not added through scripts , they are already there ! @wOxxOm

Comment: Well, must be another quirk of the quirky jQuirk. Try DOMParser: $(new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html')).find('div')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get("http://bitbaysolutions.com/", function(page) {
    $(page).find("div").each(function(){
        console.log( this.className );
    });
});
```

After calling this, I dont get the _myresult div at all, like wOxxOm said, it must be dynamically added somehow after the page loads.

You can use the code above to try to get your div through the extension page that you are using. Replace the each function and select your div properly and it might find it since the whole page is being loaded through an iframe like you said thus the scripts will also run and it should load everything.

Comment: At the end of the day either change your html code since it looks hectic anyway, or treat the response as a string and extract the data from there if you only need a little info from it.